# how to run different array on my map function for my nav component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu

Pretty new at coding so sorry if my question looks ridiculous...

I am building a menu on my website which is divided in several categories.

In this example, we have Theory and Video categories ( Video only 1 level and Theory is going deeper on 2 levels).

The code below is working for only 1 category at time (thats why the comments).

I would like to ask you how to build a more generic function that can run whatever the array is (for the map function) and avoid this: "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

```
  render() {
const theories = this.props.menuTheory; 
const videos = this.props.menuVideos;



// const menuTheory = theories.map((theory, i) => (
//
//   <div className="nav__category" key={i} onClick={() => this.onSelect(theory.category)}>
//
//     <div className={this.state.isSelected === theory.category
//       ? "nav__category__dropdown nav__category__dropdown--isSelected"
//       : "nav__category__dropdown"}>
//       <span className="nav__category__text">{theory.category}</span>
//       <span className="checked"><img src={'../static/icons/nav__check.svg'}/></span>
//     </div>
//       <ul className={this.state.isExpanded === theory.category
//         ? "nav__chapterBox"
//         : "nav__chapterBox nav__chapterBox--isNotExpanded"}>
//         {theory.chapters && theory.chapters.map((chapter, i) => <NavChapter key={i} id={chapter.objectId} title={chapter.name} onClick={() => this.onSelect1(chapter.objectId)}/>)}
//       </ul>
//   </div>
// ))

const menuVideo = videos.map((video, i) => (

  <div className="nav__category" key={i} onClick={() => this.onSelect(video.category)}>

    <div className={this.state.isSelected === video.category
      ? "nav__category__dropdown nav__category__dropdown--isSelected"
      : "nav__category__dropdown"}>
      <span className="nav__category__text">{video.category}</span>
      <span className="checked"><img src={'../static/icons/nav__check.svg'}/></span>
    </div>
  </div>
))

return (
  <nav className="nav__categoryBox">
    {/* {menuTheory} */}
    {menuVideo}
  </nav>
)
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: What line is the error happening on? If `theories` and `videos` are both arrays that exist, then the code you posted should work just fine. I'm trying to figure out what the problem is

Comment: Make sure `this.props.menuTheory` is an array and not `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks  Chase @ChaseDeAnda to try to understand me :)  this code is working fine. My goal is to find a way to return the menuVideo or menuTheory in the nav when its needed. Right now the code display the menu video. How should I write it correctly to display the theory OR video menu.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it sounds like you're looking for a way to do conditional rendering in React. What you need to do is add some state to the component. I've added `showVideos` as a bool (`true|false`). Use `showVideos` in the render method to determine which menu to show. You still create the menus using map, but in the return block, check `this.state.showVideos` to determine which content to return. To get this fully working, you'll also need to add a button that calls `toggleMenu` onClick that will update your state and switch which menu is being shown.

```
toggleMenu(){
    this.setState({
        showVideos: !this.state.showVideos
    });
}
render() {
    const theories = this.props.menuTheory; 
    const videos = this.props.menuVideos;

    const menuTheory = theories.map((theory, i) => (
        <div className="nav__category" key={i} onClick={() => this.onSelect(theory.category)}>
            <div className={this.state.isSelected === theory.category ? "nav__category__dropdown nav__category__dropdown--isSelected" : "nav__category__dropdown"}>
                <span className="nav__category__text">{theory.category}</span>
                <span className="checked"><img src={'../static/icons/nav__check.svg'}/></span>
            </div>
            <ul className={this.state.isExpanded === theory.category ? "nav__chapterBox" : "nav__chapterBox nav__chapterBox--isNotExpanded"}>
                {theory.chapters && theory.chapters.map((chapter, i) => <NavChapter key={i} id={chapter.objectId} title={chapter.name} onClick={() => this.onSelect1(chapter.objectId)}/>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    ))

    const menuVideo = videos.map((video, i) => (

        <div className="nav__category" key={i} onClick={() => this.onSelect(video.category)}>
            <div className={this.state.isSelected === video.category ? "nav__category__dropdown nav__category__dropdown--isSelected" : "nav__category__dropdown"}>
              <span className="nav__category__text">{video.category}</span>
              <span className="checked"><img src={'../static/icons/nav__check.svg'}/></span>
            </div>
      </div>
    ))

    return (
      <nav className="nav__categoryBox">
        <button onClick={this.toggleMenu}>Toggle Menu</button>
        {this.state.showVideos ? menuVideo : menuTheory}
      </nav>
    )
}
```